# first 8 bytes of CCCryptor 3DES decryption are always damaged?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cryptography

recently I am implementing an crypto algorithm which uses 3DES. However, i found that the first 8 bytes of 4096 data block are always damaged. But it is sure that it can be decrypted correctly in java. Following is my code:

```
+ (void) DecryptBy3DES:(NSInputStream*)strmSrc Output:(NSOutputStream*)strmDest CryptoRef:(CCCryptorRef)tdesCrypto
{       
    size_t  dataOutMoved;
    uint8_t inputBuf[BlockSize];
    uint8_t outputBuf[BlockSize];

    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus;
    int iBytesRead = 0;
    int iBuffUsed = 0;

    while ( (iBytesRead = [strmSrc read:inputBuf maxLength:BlockSize]) > 0 ) 
    {
        cryptStatus = CCCryptorUpdate(tdesCrypto, &inputBuf, iBytesRead, &outputBuf, BlockSize, &dataOutMoved);
        assert(cryptStatus==noErr);
        [strmDest write:outputBuf maxLength:dataOutMoved];
    }

    CCCryptorReset(tdesCrypto, nil);
}
```

where BlockSize is 4096.

I reused the CCCryptoRef tdesCrypto to decrypt several blocks. The first block to be decrypted was correct, but the following blocks all had damaged bytes at the beginning. I also try to reset the CCCryptoRef, which seems in vain.

I am really confused. Anyone has the same problem?

Comment: Don't let us guessing. What was the reason? Wrong IV?

Comment: If the first block is correct then it is probably using a zero IV.  Subsequent blocks incorrect is likely to be using the wrong mode.  Zero IV CBC, decrypted using ECB would give these symptoms.

Comment: @rossum: it seems only the first 8 bytes of each subsequent 4KiB buffer are wrong, which would not be possible if you are using ECB mode to decrypt CBC encrypted cipher text.

Comment: Please don't use the `BlockSize` name for the buffer size. The DESede block size is and always will be 8 bytes, so you are creating a lot of confusion with that name. Try `BufferSize` instead.

Comment: @HubertWang: Questions are not just for your satisfaction, they are a method of finding answers by other users as well. Please indulge us with your answer if you have one. Or accept mine if I guessed correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I got something to do that day, so this comment were left behind. I use CBC mode to ENC/DEC my file. If I don't reset the CryptoRef with the initial iv, the result will be wrong. But I don't understand why only the first 8bytes are damaged.

Comment: @SquareRootOfTwentyThree Yes, you are right. I did not reset the CryptoRef with the initial IV.

Answer (score 0):

Forget my previous answer, I deleted it. The reason that you get the "wrong bytes" in the buffer is that they are the last 8 bytes of plain text of the buffer you tried to decrypt before.

You ***must*** call `CCCryptorFinal()` right after the last call to `CCCryptorUpdate()`. This will remove the padding bytes before writing the last few bytes of plain text. Because the cipher internally does not know it the last block of the last buffer contains padding bytes, it can not write the data to the output buffer just yet.

Please do not destroy or reset the CCCryptor within your while loop. Simply add the call to `CCCryptorFinal()` right after, and don't forget to write the resulting output to stream as well. You may reset the CCCryptor after that.

I'm presuming (guessing) DESede with CBC mode and PKCS#5 padding here. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) to see what I am talking about.

Comment: Sorry for left this issue for so long and did not provide sufficient information. I did not use padding and were using CBC mode, thus I have to reset IV before next operation. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my CryptoRef:

```
CCCryptorCreateWithMode(kCCEncrypt, kCCModeCBC, kCCAlgorithm3DES, ccNoPadding, [abIV bytes], [abKey bytes], [abKey length], nil, 0, 0, kCCModeOptionCTR_BE, &cryptRef);
```

Since I use CBC mode and ccNoPadding, there is no need to call `CCCryptorFinal()`. Instead, when I finish one operation (i.e. finish encrypt/decrypt one file, etc.), I should call `CCCryptorReset()` to reset the CryptoRef's iv to initial state before next operation. Or the first block of data will be defect.

Thanks for comments and sorry for left this issue behind. I hope this could help people who encountered the same problem.